# Como os sites de compartilhamento de vídeos realizam o autoplay com áudio no chrome

Tags: vídeo, html5-video

O google chrome (desktop) tem políticas que bloqueiam o autoplay de vídeos com o áudio ligado:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#new-behaviors

Porém os sites de compartilhamento de vídeos, como globoplay, youtube, dailymotion, realizam o autoplay de vídeos com áudio no google chrome.

Qual é a configuração necessária para o google interprete o site,
 assim como os anteriormente citados, liberando o autoplay?

Answer (score 2):

O próprio HTML5 tem um atributo na tag vídeo de [autoplay](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_video_autoplay.asp)

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/movie.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: A propriedade autoplay não funciona, se o vídeo estiver com áudio, como descrito no link da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

como o colega disse em cima o próprio html5 já tem essa opção é só usar o autoplay porém está opção não dá muito certo em celulares principalmente Android por que muitos navegadores bloqueiam o autoplay e aí não tem como fazer nada mais recomendo você da uma olhada neste link para conseguir entender melhor os atributos da tag vídeo [Bem aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: A propriedade autoplay não funciona, se o vídeo estiver com áudio, como descrito no link da pergunta, porém alguns sites conseguem executar o autoplay

Comment: mais pelo o que eu sei da para utilizar a mesma opção na tag áudio também